# how to add a new row in top of a json datatable with already existing records

Tags: jquery, json, datatables

I am trying to add a row in top of a datatable which shows sum of a column "amount".I am using json datatable(jquery plugin) list to display datatable. How can i add this row in top of datatable with existing rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this code will help you

```
var json = '{ "uid": "user123", "firstName": "User", "lastName": "Theuser" }';
userTable.fnAddData(json);
```

Please refer the below link

[JsonDatatable](http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/8682/adding-a-new-row-using-pojo-or-json-not-working)

Or

At the time of fetching data from table take sum also and make it as first row