# Datatables - 2 different json sources together

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, datatables

I have 2 datatables [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jezrael/xwp3jhq1/) with 3 `json` sources. It [works](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31771607/2901002) very well.

But I need change all `json` files:

Original:

```
{
    "data": [{
        "id": "11",
        "cat1": "add1.1",
        "cat2": "add1.2",
        "cat3": "add1.3"
    }, {
        "id": "12",
        "cat1": "add2.1",
        "cat2": "add2.2",
        "cat3": "add2.3"
    }]
}
```

New: removed `{"data":`  in first 2 lines and last `}`

```
[{
    "id": "11",
    "cat1": "add1.1",
    "cat2": "add1.2",
    "cat3": "add1.3"
}, {
    "id": "12",
    "cat1": "add2.1",
    "cat2": "add2.2",
    "cat3": "add2.3"
}]
```

I hope if remove `.data` in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jezrael/xwp3jhq1/), and changed `"ajax": url` to:

```
"ajax": {
    "url": url,
    "dataSrc": ""
},
```

it will be works.

Original:

```
$.when(call1, call2).done(function(a1, a2){
        var data = a1[0].data;
        data.splice.apply(data, [2, 0].concat(a2[0].data));
        drawTable("#tab1","",data)
    }); 

drawTable("#tab2","https://api.myjson.com/bins/4lpow","")

function drawTable(id, url, data) {
    $(id).dataTable( {
     "ajax": url,
     data: data,
     columnDefs: [
        { className: "hide", "targets": [ 0 ] },
     ], 
     order: [],
     ordering: false,        
     columns: [
        { "data": "id"},
        { "data": "cat1"},
        { "data": "cat2"},
        { "data": "cat3"}
     ]
  });
}
```

New:

```
$.when(call1, call2).done(function(a1, a2){
        //removed .data
        var data = a1[0];
        //removed .data
        data.splice.apply(data, [2, 0].concat(a2[0]));  
        drawTable1("#tab11","",data)
    }); 

drawTable1("#tab21","https://api.myjson.com/bins/3tuls","")

function drawTable1(id, url, data) {
        $(id).dataTable( {
        "ajax": {
            "url": url,
            "dataSrc": ""
        },
         data: data,
         columnDefs: [
            { className: "hide", "targets": [ 0 ] },
         ], 
         order: [],
         ordering: false,        
         columns: [
            { "data": "id"},
            { "data": "cat1"},
            { "data": "cat2"},
            { "data": "cat3"}
         ]
      });
   }
```

Problem is, that it works with warning in `jsfiddle`:

> Please use POST request

If I test this [file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/c6suvymg13dmuy8/so.html) locally warning is:

> DataTables warning: table id=tab11 - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1

Comment: There is a syntax error in jsFiddle, otherwise your code works, see https://jsfiddle.net/xwp3jhq1/1/

Comment: Yes, it seems this separately works. But together only with warning. And I only need remove warning. Maybe the best is testing [file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/c6suvymg13dmuy8/so.html) locally.

Comment: @Scott Boston Sure, adfed comment and vote for delete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot provide both `ajax` and `data` options in `drawTable1` function.

Use the code below instead:

```
function drawTable1(id, url, data) {
    var opt;
    if (url !== "") {
        opt = {
            ajax: {
                url: url,
                dataSrc: ""
            }
        };
    }
    if (data !== "") {
        opt = {
            data: data
        }
    }

    $(id).dataTable($.extend({
        columnDefs: [{
            className: "hide",
            targets: [0]
        }, ],
        order: [],
        ordering: false,
        columns: [
            { "data": "id"},
            { "data": "cat1"},
            { "data": "cat2"},
            { "data": "cat3"}
        ]
    }, opt));
}
```

Comment: Super, it works very well. You can upvote question too. Thank you.